# Lit 2.0 customElements.define() throws ts(2345)

Tags: typescript, lit

After migrating several lit-Components to v2 `"lit": "2.1.1"`, we receive the following typescript error:

> Argument of type 'typeof MyComponent' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'CustomElementConstructor'.   Type 'MyComponent' is missing the
> following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey,
> accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 275 more.

```
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit';

export default class MyComponent extends LitElement {...}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent);
```

Code runs fine so far -  is this just a bug in lit?

Comment: Does this also happen, when you use the decorators? `@customElement('my-component')`. Would be easier anyways and if you are using typescript already... And which ts version are you using?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your input! Error message is gone =) I am using typescript version 4.5.4

Comment: Cool, than I post that as answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling the define function, you can use the decorator version when using typescript.

```
import { html, css, LitElement } from 'lit';
import {customElement} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('my-component')
export default class MyComponent extends LitElement {...}
```

[customElement - Class decorator factory that defines the decorated class as a custom element.](https://lit.dev/docs/api/decorators/#customElement)